# Следует ли учитывать размеры HTTP-заголовков при измерении HTTP-трафика?

Tags: http, android, ios

Я почти закончил работу над своим Open Source проектом [AFNetworkingMeter](https://github.com/stanislaw/AFNetworkingMeter), который позволяет производить измерение HTTP-трафика для любых iOS-приложений, использующих библиотеку AFNetworking.

В процессе реализации я столкнулся с вопросом:

**следует ли мне при подсчете параметра `Bytes received` наряду с телом HTTP-ответов (HTTP body) учитывать размер их заголовков (HTTP headers)?**

---

Вот простой пример:

```
Stanislaws-MacBook-Air:~ Stanislaw$ curl -i www.google.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.com.ua/?gws_rd=cr&ei=6xYzUquEL4vKsgbSmIEw
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=fe02f168d93a323b:FF=0:TM=1379079915:LM=1379079915:S=UDqzOlR4keJgeBtG; expires=Sun, 13-Sep-2015 13:45:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
... еще много несколько строк

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com.ua/?gws_rd=cr&amp;ei=6xYzUquEL4vKsgbSmIEw">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

---

Следует ли мне считать, что

**размер HTTP-ответа = размер заголовка HTTP-ответа + размер тела HTTP-ответа**

или

**размер HTTP-ответа = размер тела HTTP-ответа**

?

Буду рад увидеть ответ от знатоков HTTP-протокола и соответствующих ему RFC стандартов.

Я собираюсь сделать этот момент конфигурируемым, но в любом случае мне интересен "default" по этому вопросу.

---

**P.S.** А вот так выглядит форматированный отчет, который производит AFNetworkingMeter.

[image: AFNetworkingMeter logo]

Comment: если провайдер не взимает плату за байты в http заголовке, то не нужно конечно считать:).

Comment: Ну а если серьезно, наверняка ведь считает? Может быть оформите свои мысли в ответ? А то от шутки яснее не становится ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уважаемые участники, чтобы у вас не возникло ощущение, что я задаю совсем уж риторический вопрос, попробую пояснить, что и куда))

Начну с того, что я ожидал увидеть недоуменные вопросы: а зачем измерять трафик изнутри iOS-приложения, используя внутренние средства AFNetworking? Ведь существуют замечательные серьезные средства измерения трафика с кучей опций такие как [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), и что вроде как они прекрасно справляются с такой задачей лучше, чем самописные маленькие плагины. Попробую ответить на этот вопрос:

Мой плагин мне понадобился в нескольких узких задачах: мне нужно было просто получить представление о том, сколько трафика я сэкономлю, если произведу некие x1, x2, x3... оптимизации в своем приложении. При этом, мне было нужно посмотреть трафик создаваемый приложением не на всем цикле его жизни, а лишь, скажем, с момента полного перехода с одного ключевого скрина приложения на другой скрин. Для подобных случае плагин оказывается очень удобным, потому что я могу написать свой `[[AFNetworkingMeter sharedMeter] startMeter];`  и производить замеры произвольных кусков кода и соответственно циклов-этапов работы приложения. Так вот легко, на раз, сделать это с внешним приложением типа Fiddler это сделать было бы очень сложно. Отсюда и плагин.

Отступление - когда вы покупаете на рынке виноград и этот виноград заранее упакован в некую упаковку, на весах вы увидите суммарный вес "виноград + упаковка", и это будет справедливо, что заплатите вы за этот суммарный вес, и домой вы будете нести этот самый суммарный вес.

Но вот при условии, что я занимаюсь конкретными точечными оптимизациями определенных кусков приложения и меня интересуют какие-то отдельные куски, этапы, его работы - производить измерение *только тел HTTP-ответов* является гораздо более удобным способ быстро получить представление о том, что происходит, так как заголовки, как правило, являются "упаковкой", то есть неизменяемой частью всего материала, с которым приходится работать - заголовки, как правило, с сервера приходят совершенно одинаковые, пусть даже и не малые по размеру. То есть к отступлению выше теперь можно было добавить, что "придя домой, есть вы будете все-таки виноград, без упаковки".

Итого, **конечно же** очевидным умолчанием в моем AFNetworkingMeter будет подсчет `заголовков + ответов`, но я обязательно добавлю возможность по желанию отключать подсчет заголовков, так сказать для проведения быстрых местных ниндзя-оптимизаций и подсчета `raw content data`.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно учитывайте.

Спросите себя: "Получает ли другая сторона эти байты?" - и вопрос отпадет сам собой.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я, конечно же, тоже склоняюсь к этому. Просто ищу, так сказать, сокрушительные доводы ;)

Answer (score 2):

Привет! Заголовки передаются через соединение так же как тело; Поэтому получается что вопрос риторический )